# How can I fix the zoom for viewing landscape pages in pdf-readers?

Tags: hyperref, viewers, landscape, pdflscape

Consider this MWE and pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}% 2008/08/11 v0.10
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnRight]{hyperref}% 2012/11/06 v6.83m
\begin{document}
x \newpage
x \newpage
x
\begin{landscape}
x \newpage
x
\end{landscape}
\newpage
x \newpage
x
\end{document}
```

When opening the resulting pdf file with Adobe Reader 11.0.2 the content is shown at 64.8% size. When I scroll down and reach the landscape pages, the view is automatically changed to 50.1% to fit both pages into view. This is OK so far. But scrolling upward again (or downward for a longer document) its view size does not return to 64.8%. 
Indeed, when now using "One column, fit to window width" 100% is used, but when I chose "One column, fit to window width" immediately after opening the file without scrolling to the landscape pages then 130% is used.

Is there something I can do at the LaTeX side to get to the 64.8%/130% view size again? Entering those values manually in the pdf viewer is possible for me, but not very user friendly for possible readers of the pdf.

When using the Sumatra pdf viewer, the smaller zoom values are used already when opening the document. While this is more consistent, I would like to use the larger zoom values, maybe fixed. There are just a few landscape pages and hundreds of portrait ones, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already seen (by testing different PDF viewers), this is an issue of the PDF viewer, not the PDF file.

Comment: I had thought that maybe it would have been possible to tell the pdf viewer what to do: I assumed that the viewer's behaviour was the default for the specific viewer but that that the viewers could be told to behave otherwise. Well, if it is not possible, at least now I know that I did not miss something here. Thanks! +1 & accepted.